# How to insert the new record at the end of table without using increment column in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, model-view-controller

1. How I can insert a new record at the end of table without using the `incerment id` but with `uuid id` only ?
2. Is using `index` column in addation to `id` column is the best way to order the table rows by index or new items ? or i should only use 1 column and specify the order by another way ? If yes, what is the other way to make it?

I created a simple table called `users` in the database, and this table include 4 columns:

- `index`: Increment
- `id`: UUID - Primary key
- `name`: String
- `email`: String

and I want to hide the users id so I used the `id` column as `UUID` to use it in the apis and hide it oustside the database, and I added the `index` column to sort the table by index when create a new record.

I expected to order the table by index but the table still ordered by id because it's the primary key.

Comment: SQL has no inherent order. You always have to provide an `order by` clause if you want an order.

Comment: 1) There is no end of the table, tuples are unordered. 2) Is `index` using a `serial` or `identity` auto increment? 3) If 2) is yes then don't include `index` in the INSERT and the value will change on its own.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the end of the table". You can't control where the database will physically place the inserted row, nor what order the database will return rows unless you use a `order by` clause. Any solution will involve populating a column that can be used by an `order by` clause.

Comment: Alright, so I should use the id only as UUID and let the database handle the sort and order them when fetch the records from the table

Comment: In case I want to use the id as a serial and hide it outside the database for example in the apis, what is the best way to make it? 

Use the UUID instead the serial or there is a better way?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you use `index` as `serial` or `identity` as you have declared `id` to be `UUID`. You seem to be trying to have two different PK's as since there can only be one I am not seeing the point of the  `index` column?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm only using the id column to hide the table roes counts in the APIs response.
I created 2 columns but the id column is the primary key, not both
But I think it' right and no need for the index column and I will only use the id column